# Angular 2 - how to update model

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I receive data model using a service:

```
  return this.http.get(queryUrl, opts)   .map((response: Response) => {
    return (<any>response.json()).data.map(el => {
      return new User({
        id: item.id,
        name : item.name
      });
    })
```

This gets accesed from component

```
      makeRequest() {
          this.result = this.myService.loadData()
      }
```

And passed down as `result: Observable<User[]>;` to a form, this on Submit sends a post request which gets saved to the backend,all this works. The problem is that my model/website doesn't get updated this way.

Probably it's a silly question but, how do I update my model (now after saving to backend the app still holds the old data)? What ar the strategies? Do I have to pass updated data object back to top component and then update?

Comment: what is the response you are getting after this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is easier than I thought...

When you get a list of users and save it to an array, you need to just updates that array... In Angular2 all responses returned from http.get are Observables it is enough to just subscribe to the http.get and the app will update the results for you.